# How to print the detailed type of a struct type in LLVM IR which is compiled from a CPP class?

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir

After compiling a class in C++ to LLVM bitcode, I use `llvm-dis` or `opt -S` to display the textual IR, but the printed type of that class is always like: `%class.A = type { i32 (...)** }`

Does anyone know how to print the detailed type that is current hidden by `...`?

Here is the C++ code that I use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class A {
  public:
    virtual int foo(int i) {
      return i + 2;
    }
};

int main() {
  A *a = new A;
  int x = a->foo(1);
  return 0;
}
```

And here is part of the output LLVM IR:

```
; ModuleID = 'logs/abstract.bc'
source_filename = "abstract.cpp"
target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

%class.A = type { i32 (...)** }              // How to make ... become more detailed?

$_ZN1AC2Ev = comdat any
$_ZN1A3fooEi = comdat any
$_ZN1A3barEi = comdat any
$_ZTV1A = comdat any
$_ZTS1A = comdat any
$_ZTI1A = comdat any
....
```

Comment: FYI, the struct type is fine, your problem is that the function type is that of a vararg function. `...` hides nothing, it says "vararg". Now, why is it like that? No idea, and you don't mention how you produce the IR.

Comment: Hi, my compilation command is: `clang -O0 -c -emit-llvm abstract.cpp`. And I use `opt -S` to display the bitcode

Comment: Isn't `vararg` in a form like: `(i8*, ...)`, whose first type is explicit?

Comment: @arnt: I think you maybe right that `...` actually represents varargs. In the above code, I compile a class with a virtual function. The varargs feature may be used to store that virtual function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing hidden here.

Your class contains a single virtual function. So, the corresponding struct should have a place to hold function pointer.